# get all lines NOT end with 'rpms' in sed

Tags: regex, sed

I want to append following line to those lines. If you have any good tips, please let me know. Thanks a lot.

I have tried

```
sed -e '/?!(rpms$)/{N;s/\n//}' filename
```

But failed.

Comment: Edit your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output to we can start to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for that to put lines that don't end with rpms on a single line:

```
sed -e ':a;/rpms$/!{N;s/\n//;ba}'
```

Instead of trying to negate a pattern, you can negate the test itself putting the negation operator `!` after the pattern.

To handle the case where there are more than two lines without rpms at the end, I added the label `:a` and the unconditional jump `ba` to this label.

Comment: perfect and easy to understand. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly (wild guessing), you want all lines removed/deleted that have `rpms` at the end. Then match just that (`rpms$`) and use the delete command `/.../d`

```
sed -e '/rpms$/d' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;s/rpm\n/rpm/;ta;P;D' file
```

Read two lines into the pattern space and if the first line ends in `rpm` remove the following newline and repeat. Otherwise print the first line then delete it and append the next and line and repeat.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly help. I have tried, but the result is not the same as expected.